# Add unit test to unit test session or to Nunit, by list of unit test case names

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, resharper-7.1

We are having almost 20000 unit test written for project and if I make any change which can fail existing unit test. Now there are almost 100 unit test are failing and I have list of unit test case failing.

Question is there any way I can add all those 100 failing unit test cases either resharper unit test session or to Nunit.

Is there any nunit adapter or resharper extension that will allow me to give list of unit test case names either from file like csv file add it to nunit or resharper unit session?

Those failing unit test cases can be from different category. I need to manually run or add to unit test session.

Answer (score 0):

You could use NUnit console,

nunit-console /runlist:testlist.txt nunit.tests.dll

Refer : http://nunit.org/index.php?p=consoleCommandLine&r=2.6.3